# How to remove loop in this JQuery snippet?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a little JQuery snippet that is executed when the "Add to cart" button is pressed. The page basically has multiple products with separate add to cart button. So when this button is pressed, a loop is created which evaluates each product quantity and adds only the item of which "Add to cart" button is pressed. I want to remove the loop in this snippet. Let me know if any additional details are needed.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $('.addtocartbtn a').on('click', function (e) {
        var link = this;
        var itemname = $('#Content1_lblName').html().replace(/Adopt a /g, '');
        var itemregex = new RegExp(' ' + itemname, 'g');
        var itemlevel = $(link).parent().parent().prev('h3').html().replace(itemregex, '');
        var box = link.parentNode.previousSibling;
        var quant = box.id;
        while (!quant) {
            box = box.previousSibling;
            quant = box.id;
        }
        if (box.value < 1 || /\D/.test(box.value)) {
            $(box).next().next().css("display", "block");
        } else {
            $('.quantity').each(function () {
                if ($(this).attr('id') != quant) $(this).val('');
                else {
                    dataLayer.push({
                        'gtmCategory': 'Page Type',
                        'gtmAction': 'Species Adoption Add to Cart',
                        'gtmLabel': itemname + " Set of  (" + $(this).val() + ") (" + itemlevel.toString().substr(level.toString().indexOf('$'), 4).trim() + ")",
                        'event': 'gtmEvent'
                    });
                }
            });
            __doPostBack('content1$btnAddToCart', '');
        }
        (e.preventDefault) ? e.preventDefault() : e.returnValue = false;
    }); </script>
```

Attached the picture of how the page will look like. With the current snippet, all the items are added to the cart when one button is pressed. But my actual requirement is only the selected item must be added to the cart.

[Page image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iYpg.jpg)

Below is the sample HTML markup:

```
 <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="Content1" runat="Server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="scriptManager" runat="server" AsyncPostBackTimeout="300" />
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="updatePanel">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div class="span9">
            <a id="breadcrumb" runat="server" href="https://www.google.com/" class="hdr-important"><strong>Sample breadcrumb</strong></a>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="span4 push-right">
                    <div class="break-gutter-horiz gutter-bottom-2">
                        <img runat="server" id="imgMain" alt="" src="" width="320" height="213" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="span5 no-gutter gutter-bottom-fixed-2">
                    <div class="wysiwyg break-gutter-horiz more-less">
                        <p id="lblFacts" runat="server"></p>
                    </div>


                </div>
            </div>

            <asp:Repeater ID="itemlist" runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>

                    <div class="accordion gutter-bottom-4">
                        <div class="accordion-item expanded gutter-bottom-fixed-4">
                            <div class="break-gutter-horiz">

                                <asp:HiddenField ID="itemid" runat="server" />

                                <asp:Literal ID="mostPopularDiv" runat="server"></asp:Literal>

                                <h3 id="itemnameheader" class="hdr hdr-tertiary">
                                    <asp:Literal ID="itemleveltitle" runat="server"></asp:Literal></h3>

                                <div class="accordion-content show">

                                    <asp:Literal ID="itemDetailsLink" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                                    <asp:Literal ID="itemDetailsDivId" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                                    <asp:Literal ID="itemDetailsContent" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                                </div>


                                <label for="quantity1"><strong>Quantity</strong></label>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="quantitydropdown" runat="server" Enabled="true" >
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="1">1</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="2">2</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="3">3</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="4">4</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="5">5</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="6">6</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="7">7</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="8">8</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="9">9</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="10">10</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem 
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                                <span class="addtocartbtn"><a class="btn-orange btn-simple btn-break-block" href="#">Add to Cart</a></span>

                            </div>
                         </div>
                    </div>

                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Would be easier if you also included the rendered HTML... For one thing, that's some scary DOM navigation going on there, with a strange mix of jQuery and normal DOM methods. Might be an easier way to include the relevant data in the links as `data-` attributes rather than searching all over the DOM...

Comment: I have added the markup picture as link here

Comment: That's great, but we need the structure of the HTML code (as text). Try right-clicking and selecting View Source.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that @MikeMcCaughan means the actual HTML code.

Comment: HTML markup added

Comment: Can someone help with this question?